# How do I search my own answers.

Tags: support, search

This morning I wanted to find an answer of mine proving that some plane curve is not hyperelliptic.
So I typed [*not hyperelliptic Georges Elencwajg*](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=not+hyperelliptic+Georges+Elencwajg) in the search box and got a message reading "0 results".
But when I typed just [*not hyperelliptic*](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=not+hyperelliptic)  I got 92 results, of which the very first contained my answer !
So, how do I search efficiently for an answer that I gave to a question whose exact formulation I forgot?

Comment: Some older related posts (where restriction to a particular user was mentioned): [How to intersect users and tags?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051/how-to-intersect-users-and-tags), [How to look up users' specific answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/how-to-look-up-users-specific-answers) and [How to search for postings of user X with tag Y?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21597/how-to-search-for-postings-of-user-x-with-tag-y).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Martin. I am embarrassed to confess that I had completely forgotten about my previous similar question ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add "[user:me is:a](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aa)" to your search parameters.

Comment: Fantastic, it works fine! Thanks a lot, Asaf. Just for my edification, could you please roughly explain what that code is? (Which will also help me remember that unexpected string of characters !)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "is:a" is short for "is:answer" which would also work, and means the post is an answer (and not a questions which would be indicaeted by is:question or is:q). "user:" restricts to the posts of a certain user, which user is usually specified by giving their user number but there is a shortcut for one's own posts which is "me" More information is on http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching also note that when you perform a simple search, you will the have on the page that give the result a link "advanced search tips" that can serve for quick look-ups.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In addition the [help on search](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the help center, which was already mentioned by quid, I will mention that you can find Advanced Search Tips [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search). (You have to click on the caption "Advanced Search Tips", so that it expands.)

Comment: Thanks for the  explanation, @quid.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for your new comment and your *edit* which will make future searches childishly simple!

Comment: @Georges: But when you'll forget the link to this answer, how will you find it? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: I guess you're joking but the sad truth is that this really worries me. I jotted down your answer in a special exercise book, and I hope I will remember which one! In the worst-case scenario I'll ask again here and I hope you will still be as helpful as you have been today...

Comment: @Georges: Well, I hope you'll just remember that there is an "advanced search tips" guide on the side of the search results. But if it comes to asking again, I guess we'll have to wait and see. I have no plans on being less helpful anytime soon.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Wouldn't a better solution how to mark a useful stuff be adding it to [your favorites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites) (or using some other online solution)? You know, the exercise book might not be at you when you come here, but favorites are just a few clicks away.

Comment: Excellent idea, @Martin: done!